# Unable to split array by comma

Tags: java, html, servlets

I pass an array(of floats) as a hidden form field from JSP to Servlet. At the servlet side, I do

```
String str=request.getParameter("floatArray"); // returs 0,0.07
String[] strArray=str.split(" , ");
```

Still, when I try to retrieve the first element of the strArray, it returns 0, 0.07.

How do I separate the two float values?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the spaces from your split..?

Comment: You probably want the regex to split for any number of spaces followed by a comma followed by any number of spaces.

Comment: you have spaces in your delimiter for spliting

Comment: thankyou all.. been overloaded.. overlooked the spaces :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
String[] strArray=str.split(" , ");
```

To this:

```
String[] strArray = str.split("\\s*,\\s*")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

Comment: If you're sure you will never have spaces in your result, you could also just use .split(",") to keep things simpler.